# How to remove duplicate mypy error lines in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy

When mypy reports errors in my VSCode 'PROBLEMS' terminal, every error seems to be duplicated. I'm not sure whether this is VSCode specific or just a mypy issue.

Example :

```
Returning Any from function declared to return "floating[_32Bit]" mypy [Ln 123, Col 123]
Returning Any from function declared to return "floating[_32Bit]" mypy(error) [Ln 123, Col 123]
```

What do I have to do to only get 1 line per error ?

Answer (score 0):

### Root cause

You likely have more than one extension that is type checking with mypy. For example, I had installed mypy and also allowed the Python extension to lint with mypy.

### To solve (see image):

1. Open settings and type "mypy"
2. Choose one of the extensions on the left
3. Disable Mypy linting for that extension

[image: Annotated screenshot of VSCode settings panel]

Comment: Unfortunately this was already disabled in my case, and my errors are still duplicated :(